# Exclude one folder and a filetype from Get-childitem

Tags: powershell, directory, compression, get-childitem

I have a website that needs frequent backup hence I would like to write a script to compress all the files in the screenshot. Except:

1. All the contents in the *image* folder (See Highlighted)
2. Any *.log files in the entire directory

[image]

I tried to get a list of files and always end up having the image folders contents:

```
$WebAppFolder = 'C:\ReleaseBackupScript\MyWebSite'
$filteredList = Get-childitem -path $WebAppFolder -exclude $WebAppFolder"\image",*.log -Name -recurse -force
Out-File -FilePath FilteredList.txt -InputObject $filteredList
```

Comment: `-exclude` works on the **Name** property of the objects returned. For the image folder you are adding the complete path..

Comment: @Theo then how abt the contents inside image folder... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) notes, as of as of PowerShell 7.2:

- `-Exclude` (as well as `-Include` and `-Filter`) operate on file and directory *names* only, not on *paths*.
- Similarly, `-Exclude` doesn't support excluding entire directory *subtrees* (a directory and all its content).

Overcoming these limitations in a future PowerShell version for `-Include` and `-Exclude` is being discussed in [GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159).

Therefore, you'll have to perform your own post-filtering yourself:

```
$WebAppFolder = 'C:\ReleaseBackupScript\MyWebSite'
$filteredList = 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -File -Name -LiteralPath $WebAppFolder -Exclude *.log |
    Where-Object { $_ -notlike 'image\*' } > FilteredList.txt
```

Note: Since you're using [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-Name` parameter, the output objects are *strings*, namely *relative paths*, which is why each input object  to the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (reflected in [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)) is matched as whole against a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) that matches strings that start with `image\`.

Without `-Name`, [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances would be output, in which case you'd have to use the following filter command:
`Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike '*\image\*' }` or - using `Where-Object`'s [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax):
`Where-Object FullName -notlike *\image\*`

<sup>Note that, as of PowerShell 7.2, simplified syntax is currently *not* available for operations performed on the input object *as a whole*, because the name of a *property* to operate on is required. That is,

`Where-Object -notlike *\image\*` - with the LHS operand *implicitly* being the whole input object (`$_`) - does *not* work, though supporting that is being discussed in [GitHub issue #8357](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8357).</sup>